# jQuery ajax error not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: formsubmission,
    data: data,
    success: function() {
        alert("E-mail Sent");
        $("#submit").replaceWith('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onclick="send_email()">Submit</button>')
    }
    Error: function() {
        alert("E-mail Fail");
        $("#submit").replaceWith('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="submit" onclick="send_email()">Submit</button>')
    }
})
```

Anyone can please tell me Why Error function is not working? How can I resolve it?

Comment: It's `error` not `Error` and you should put a comma before it

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into this and check if you still have problem triggering the `error` function of your `ajax` call, and also instead of replacing the whole element in your error function, I removed the `'btn-primary'` class and added `'btn-danger'` class to make it shorter.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: formsubmission,
    data: data,
    success: function() {
        alert("E-mail Sent");
        $("#submit").replaceWith('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onclick="send_email()">Submit</button>')
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("E-mail Fail");
        $("#submit").removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger');
    }
});
```